ES7 React/Redux/GraphQL/React-Native not working
The extension is not working even though I have it installed properly in VS Code. When I try to use CTRL + ALT + R which is a search command for ES7, nothing popped up, not even simply searching es7 on the search tab. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling, and relaunching VS Code. None worked. With further research I came upon this StackOverflow Question which has my problem in it but I was unable to do what the answers suggested. Most had to do with JSON settings, but if I'm being honest I have no idea how to navigate the JSON settings. Is there an extra step I am supposed to take to make it work properly? I am working on a JSX file so it should theoretically work.
Did anyone else have this problem?


my JSON setting is set to "editor.suggest.showSnippets": true, and "editor.quickSuggestions":
"other": true,
